# setState of many items React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, setstate

I am trying to build a news app that displays top 20 articles per country. However, I tried putting my setState call inside a loop but I quickly realized that they were being overwritten and the only one that would display is the last one. I was wondering how could I achieve this without overriding the previous entries. Thank you in advance!

```
//the following code is inside my App.js file and inside the App component
getNews = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const country = e.target.elements.country.value;
const api_call = await fetch(this.buildURL(country));
const data = await api_call.json();

  if (country) {
    console.log(data);

    //i changed this to just display the first article out of 20
    this.setState({
        title: data.articles[0].title,
        image: data.articles[0].urlToImage,
        description: data.articles[0].description,
        author: data.articles[0].author,
        link: data.articles[0].url,
        err: ""
    });
  }
  else {
    this.setState({
      title: undefined,
      image: undefined,
      description: undefined,
      author: undefined,
      link: undefined,
      err: "Please enter valid country"
    });
  }


}

  render() {
      return(
      <div>
        <Titles />
        <Form getNews={this.getNews}/>
        <News title={this.state.title}
              image={this.state.image}
              description={this.state.description}
              author={this.state.author}
              link={this.state.link}
              err={this.state.err}
        />
      </div>
    );
    }
```

This is a beginners project so pls keep that in mind haha.

Comment: What kind of response do you get from your API? can you edit the question so we can understand better?

Comment: Also, having a bit more of your app code helps. From the looks of it though I do not see anything looping over your response data to store articles, nor do I see in the render function some array map function to render the resultant array of articles.

Answer (score 1):

So you want include all news items in state, then loop over them and create a News element for each of them. Something like this for the request:

```
getNews = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const country = e.target.elements.country.value;
  if (!country) {
    this.setState({
      articles: null,
      err: "Please enter valid country"
    });
  }
  let data;
  try {
    data = await fetch(this.buildURL(country)).then(res => res.json());
  } catch (error) {
    this.setState({
      articles: null,
      err: "Please enter valid country"
    });
  }
  if (data) {
    this.setState({
      articles: data.map(article => ({
        title: article.title,
        image: article.urlToImage,
        description: article.description,
        author: article.author,
        link: article.url
      }))
    });
  }
};
```

although I do not guarantee it is bug free!

Then when you have all articles in state, you can loop over them:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Titles />
      <Form getNews={this.getNews} />

      {this.state.articles.map(article => (
        <News
          title={article.title}
          image={article.image}
          description={this.state.description}
          author={article.author}
          link={article.link}
          err={article.err}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

or you can spread the props like this, if you know the object key names you stored in state match exactly those the News component expects:

```
  {this.state.articles.map(article => (
    <News {...article}/>
  ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state should have an array instead of just provision for one object.

```
this.setState({
    title: data.articles[0].title,
    image: data.articles[0].urlToImage,
    description: data.articles[0].description,
    author: data.articles[0].author,
    link: data.articles[0].url,
    err: ""
});
```

Should be changed to something like the following.

```
var articles = this.state.articles.slice();
var newArticle = {
    title: data.articles[0].title,
    image: data.articles[0].urlToImage,
    description: data.articles[0].description,
    author: data.articles[0].author,
    link: data.articles[0].url,
    err: ""
};
articles.push(newArticle);

this.setState(articles);
```

Also note that `setState` is asynchronous. So sometimes, you should use the existing state to determine the new value of state. Refer [setState documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)